# Execute Batch File With Different Process Name

Tags: windows, batch-file, process, cmd, taskmanager

I have 6 different batch scripts that I am running together at the same time. The problem is, it is difficult to differentiate between them in the Windows Task Manager because the process is always just **cmd.exe** I was wondering if there was a way to change the process name for a batch script to something else so that each script would be more identifiable.

I have done a lot of research on this topic so far, and the only lead that I have is creating a copy of **cmd.exe** in system32 that has a different name, one of my choosing. The problem is, I am not sure how I would get my bash script to use this new executable with a different name, rather than the default cmd.exe

**Requirement:** Must use only built in Windows functionality. I do not want to install any other programs if possible.

Comment: What if you use `TITLE` command ?In the newer taskmanagers win7/8..  you can see the title of the process

Comment: This won't work for what I need because it only changes the window title. I need the **process name** to be changed so that when I go to Windows Task Manager > Processes, I can see something other than cmd.exe

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with something like the subroutine below.  The reason for the first goto is so that you don't fall into the subroutine when you are done. I incorporate another FOR loop to iterate through a list of filenames to check.  Let's get this working first.

```
Your existing bat file goes here
CALL :IsitRunning "SomeFileName"
The rest of your existing bat file goes here
GOTO :eof

:IsitRunning
REM 1=Filename
FOR /F "delims=" %%A in ('WMIC PROCESS WHERE NAME^='CMD.EXE' LIST FULL ^| FINDSTR /I "%~1" ^| FINDSTR /I /V WMIC') DO ECHO(%~1 is running
GOTO :eof
```

Or you can run this command from a CMD prompt.

```
wmic process WHERE NAME='cmd.exe' list full | findstr /i "SomeFileName.bat"
```

Comment: Is there any way that I could incorporate this functionality into my bat file so that I dont have to have 2 separate files? Also, I think you're missing a closed parenthesis in there.

Comment: No missing parenthesis.  You may be confused by ECHO(.  Use ECHO. instead if you like.  I will edit to show usage.

Comment: I tested the posted code and it does work.  For example if you want to see if pin.bat is running, replace SomeFileName with pin.bat.  I use something similar to iterate through a list of filenames and post a message if any are running. Need to add a count if you need to check for another copy of this bat file is running because there will obviously be this copy... I want to know if another copy is running.  Maybe to simplify things we should start by running this from a CMD prompt.   wmic process WHERE NAME='cmd.exe' list full | findstr /i "pin.bat"

Answer (score 1):

You can see command line in Task Manager, turn it on *View* menu - *Choose Columns*.

If you want to change process name you have to change the process. So your approach is only way.